# Login to docker registry with client certificate under windows

Tags: windows, docker, docker-registry, client-certificates

The docker documentation [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/certificates/) describes how to configure docker in order to connect to a registry that requires a client certificate. Under Ubuntu it works: I place the `client.crt` and `client.key` files into the folder `/etc/docker/certs.d/<myregistry>/` as stated by the documentation ... and it works.

Unfortunately, there is no specific documentation how to configure docker under windows (wsl backend) to achieve the same result... and I stuck... I performed following attempts:

- Imported the private key and certificate into the windows certificate manager, restarted docker
- added the cert and key files into the `docker-desktop` wsl file system in `/etc/docker/certs.d/<myregistry>/`, restarted docker...
- added the cert and key files into the `docker-desktop-data` wsl file system in `/etc/docker/certs.d/<myregistry>/`, restarted docker
- added the cert and key files into the `docker-desktop` wsl file system in `/root/.docker/certs.d/<myregistry>/`, restarted docker
- added the cert and key files into the `docker-desktop-data` wsl file system in `/root/.docker/certs.d/<myregistry>/`, restarted docker

I always get the same result:

```
PS C:\> docker login -u <remote_user> <myregistry>
Password:
Error response from daemon: login attempt to https://<myregistry>/v2/ failed with status: 400 Bad Request
```

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it! You need to place the cert and key files into the `C:\Users\<user>\.docker\certs.d\<mysite>\` as follows:

```
C:\Users\<user>\.docker\certs.d\<mysite>\client.cert
C:\Users\<user>\.docker\certs.d\<mysite>\client.key
```

Docker must be restarted and after that, the login with the command `docker login <mysite>` does not fail anymore.